# Use multiple %s for formating output names in Python

Tags: python, ipython

I would like to dynamically create multiple filenames in a nested loop let's say for 2 participants where each participant has different 4 sessions. My goal is to create filenames like:

- Learning_S1_P1.xlsx; Learning_S2_P1.xlsx; Learning_S3_P1.xlsx; Learning_S4_P1.xlsx
- Learning_S1_P2.xlsx; ... Learning_S4_P2.xlsx

My code is:

```
filename = {}
for y in range(0,4):
    for i in range(0,2):
        filename[y][i] = 'Learning_S%s_P%s.xlsx' % (1+y,1+i)
```

However, I receive KeyError: 0. I am blocked and couldn't find out the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has nothing at all to do with your string formatting. The error is coming when you attempt to set items in your dict. That's because you're attempting to set items in a nested dict, without ever creating the inner dictionary: `filename[y]` does not exist, so you can't do `filename[y][i]`.

You could fix this by creating a dict in the outer loop:

```
filename = {}
for y in range(0,4):
    filename[y] = {}
    for i in range(0,2):
        filename[y][i] = 'Learning_S%s_P%s.xlsx' % (1+y,1+i)
```

although I would question whether dicts are the right data structure here: seems like nested lists would be more appropriate:

```
filename = []
for y in range(0,4):
    inner = []
    for i in range(0,2):
        inner.append('Learning_S%s_P%s.xlsx' % (1+y,1+i))
    filename.append(inner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with strings.
You get KeyError because you write

```
filename[y][i]
```

write

```
filename[y] = {}
filename[y][i] = 'whatever'
```

(And you may use format() instead of the %s syntax.)

Advice: when facing this kind of issue, try to separate the line in several statements.

This line is fine by itself:

```
filename[y][i] = 'Learning_S%s_P%s.xlsx' % (1+y,1+i)
```

but when it raises an Exception, cut it in two:

```
value = 'Learning_S%s_P%s.xlsx' % (1+y,1+i)    
filename[y][i] = value
```

It will be obvious that the error is raised by the second line, and has nothing to do with strings.